# Trouble adding up value xml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm looking to increment an XML node by 1 each time a visitor visits the page.

Here is what I currently have, but it keeps returning a value of 1...

```
<?php

$xPostName =   $xml->up;

//load xml file to edit

$xml = simplexml_load_file($_GET['id'].'/info.xml');

$xml->up = $xPostName +1;

// save the updated document

$xml->asXML($_GET['id'].'/info.xml');

echo "done";

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you set `$xPostName` before you load the file, so there is no value at this point, and then add 1 to this to update the value...

```
$xPostName =   $xml->up;
//load xml file to edit
$xml = simplexml_load_file($_GET['id'].'/info.xml');
$xml->up = $xPostName +1;
```

So move this to after loading the file...

```
//load xml file to edit
$xml = simplexml_load_file($_GET['id'].'/info.xml');
$xPostName =   $xml->up;
$xml->up = $xPostName +1;
```

Or just increment the value directly...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('out.xml');

$xml->up +=1;
```